# How to set a pandas DataFrames column value based on a condition applied to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe to which I want to add another column and that depends on the values based on what other column in that particular cell.

I keep getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`.

Here is my dataframe: df where all columns' values are in string format

```
ID      Key
_1      A
_2       B, C
_3       A
_4       D, E
_5       B, C
```

My expected output is

```
ID      Key      Name
_1       A        n0, n1
_2       B, C     n2
_3       A        n3
_4       D, E     n4
_5       B, C     n5, n6
```

Here is what I did:

```
df[df['ID'].str.contains('1')]['Name'] = 'n0, n1' that gave me Type Error.
```

Note here that the id matching is a substring match which is intentional.

Tried using `numpy where` but that also gave me the same error. I followed [This link](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_create_column_using_conditional/).

What is the correct way to set a new column's value that is based on subset of a column's values. Also, I cover all values later where I do this for every `ID` (here from 1 to 5).

Comment: How does the 1 become _1 (and other numbers) in the expected result?

Comment: @Valentino: Sorry about the typo. I corrected it.

Comment: is `df['Name'] = df['ID'].apply(your_function)` what you are searching for? your_function takes the ID as input and returns the value for Name in that particular row

Comment: And how do you correlate A, B, etc with n0, n1 etc? I don't see the logic.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, it takes a substring of ID as an input and matches against the value for ID column and return Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
df.loc[df['ID'].str.contains('1'), 'Name'] = 'n0, n1'
```

Basically you need to use .loc[row_index, col_index] = val to modify an existing dataframe.

Using df[row_index][col_index] just creates a copy of the value I believe.

This is also assuming you've already defined the column:

```
df['Name'] = pd.Series()
```